# Difficulty understanding the proof of equivalence of all norms over $\mathbb R^{n}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

To  prove  that  all  norms  are  equivalent  on  $\mathbb  R^{n}$  ,  the  book  I   am  reading  ,  first  takes  an  arbitrary  norm  $$|\ \ | \ :\ \mathbb R^{n}\rightarrow\ \mathbb R$$  and  then  writes  $$|x|\le \sum_i |x_i||e_i| \le C\sum_i |x_i| \le C\sum_i \|x\|_{2} \le Cn\|x\|_2 $$ Where  $e_i$  are  the  canonical  basis  vectors  of  $\mathbb R^{n}$  and  $C=max\{ |e_i|\ :\ 1\le  i \le n  \ \}$  and  $\|\ \ \|_{2}$   is  the  $L^{2}$  norm  on  $\mathbb R^{n}$

The  one  part  of  this  inequality  that  I  cannot  understand  is  $$C\sum_{i} |x_{i}| \le C\sum_i\|x\|_2$$ 
   The  norm  $|\ \ |$  is  any  arbitrary  norm  on  $\mathbb  R^{n}$  ,  not  the  modulus   norm  of  $\mathbb R$,which ,  had  the  case  been ,  I  could  understand  the  inequality .

Although  from  the  very  few  norms on  the  reals  that  I  have  been  introduced  this  far  I  could  not  find  any  that  can  satisfy 
   $$ |x_i| \gt \|x\|_2$$ but  how  to  prove  that
$$ |x_i| \le \|x\|_{2}$$  is  true  in  general  for  all  norms  on  $\mathbb R^n$?

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: $x_i$ is a real number, and $|x_i|$ is its absolute value... What do you think "$x = \sum_i x_i e_i$" means?

Comment: But  it  says  $|\ |$  an  arbitrary  norm ,  not  necessarily  the  modulus .

Comment: Yes, for elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}^n$. What would "the modulus" be for an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ anyway? The notation $|\;|$ is used for two different things here: an arbitrary norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the usual absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$. It's unfortunate but the context makes things clear.

Comment: Yeah its not terribly great notation but they mean for $x, e_i$ to be vectors, so $|x|, |e_i|$ are their norms. But $x_i$ are real numbers so $|x_i|$ can only be absolute value.

Comment: So  them  using  same  notation  for  two  different  things !?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  :  So  is  it  that  $\mathcal  modulus $  is  the   only  possible  norm  on  $\mathbb R$  $?$  Sorry  if  this  sounds   really  stupid ,  but  I  am   a  little  confused .

Comment: No, it's not the only norm (for example $x \mapsto 2 |x|$ is still a norm), it's just the one that's used here on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  :  But  the  norm  you  gave  is  equivalent  to  the  modulus  norm . Must  be ,  since  $\mathbb R$  is  also  finite  dimensional . But  can  we  have  a  different  proof  for  $\mathbb R$ . ?  Or  how  can  I  presume  safely  that  modulus  was  the  norm  used  here  $?$

Comment: @user118494: You can safely presume that $|x_i|$ denotes the modulus because it is just a standard convention of notation that it always means that when $x_i$ is a real number (for this reason, the book's choice of $|\cdot|$ to denote an arbitrary norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n$ might happen to be $1$ is rather poor).  Note also that if this were not the case, you should also be confused by the inequality $|x|\leq\sum |x_i| |e_i|$.

Comment: @EricWofsey  :  OK  but  about  the  last  line  of  your  comment , I  don't  agree . That  inequality  is  derived  from  the  triangle  inequality ,  true  for  any  and  every  norm .

Comment: The triangle inequality says that $|x|=\left|\sum x_i e_i\right|\leq \sum |x_i e_i|$.  But you only know that $|x_ie_i|=|x_i||e_i|$ if on the right-hand side, $|x_i|$ denotes the modulus of $x_i$.

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives you what you want more directly:
$$
        \sum_{i}|x_i||e_i| \le \left(\sum_i|x_i|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_i|e_i|^{2}\right)^{1/2}=C\|x\|_{2}.
$$
$|x_i| = (|x_i|^{2})^{1/2} \le (|x_1|^{2}+\cdots+|x_n|^{2})^{1/2} = \|x\|_2$ answers your last question. This gives
$$
                 C\sum_i |x_i| \le C\sum_i \|x\|_2=Cn\|x\|_2
$$